# Beautiful soup add a tag with attributes and save it

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, attributes, tags, append

Using an InterShop XML file, I need to add the following tag inside a  tag using Python and BeautifulSoup.

What I'd like is to write this :

```
valueNouveau = soup.new_tag('custom-attribute', {"name" : "ImagesWEB"},{"xml:lang" : "fr-FR"})
valueNouveau.string = 'chaine'
tagKeywords.append(valueNouveau)
```

when I do this it fails when writing the file with msg

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str' File
"/Users/cchauvin/Documents/Synonymes/Synoymes_etcetera.py", line 116,
in main f_output.write(str(soup))
```

When I write this, everything runs smoothly and my file is written

```
valueNouveau = soup.new_tag('custom-Chauvin') 
valueNouveau.string ='chaine' 
tagKeywords.append(valueNouveau)
```

What's wrong ? I need to add this tag in the existing xml file

```
 <custom-attribute name="ImagesWEB" dt:dt="string" xml:lang="fr-FR">
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not pass every attribute of a tag in unique dictionaries, just create a single dictionary and put all the attributes you want inside it and pass it into the method. Like this:

```
dict_attributes = {"name" : "ImagesWEB",
            "xml:lang" : "fr-FR"}
valueNouveau = soup.new_tag('custom-attribute',attrs=dict_attributes)
valueNouveau.string = 'chaine'
tagKeywords.append(valueNouveau)
```

Output:

```
<custom-attribute name="ImagesWEB" xml:lang="fr-FR">chaine</custom-attribute>
```